# iOS 9 beta installation why on earth are they asking me for the device model?

Tags: download, installation, ios9

When downloading iOS 9 beta I am asked to specify which model phone I am going to use. Why is this? I have several devices and each build is big so it feels kind of crazy to have to do so for each device.

Answer (score 1):

I asked that question too to one of the engineers at apple as I was curious. This is because they have different internal architectures and specifications. So for example the iPad 2 can run a way stronger and heavier build of iOS 9 with more features than the normal iPad. The same thing goes for the iPhone 6 Plus and the iPhone 4S, as both are supported however they have different types of capabilities. The iPhone 6 Plus can run the normal beta smoothly, as it has a good processor and not slow down, whereas the iPhone 4S needs an optimised bra to run smoothly. Later when the general release is taking place, the selection of OS happens automatically, as the Device Identifier is at hand and automatically checked by apple. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: That's good thanks. So is there a way to avoid downloading n version of iOS 9 for each n devices I am using? I got around 5/6 devices and it seems overkill. Or shall I just download Xcode 7 with iOS 9?

Comment: Well, there's no way, as each seed is made for the device's specific architecture. Sorry. Also if my answer helped if you wouldn't mind accepting it please? Thanks